# Boxplot of specific groups and all groups using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have an example data set which represents my bigger data set I'm dealing with that looks like this:

```
dat <- data.frame(groupid = c(rep("2ppm", 5), rep("20ppm", 5)),
var1 = c(222, 212, 245, 233, 213, 444, 454, 464, 434, 424),
var2 = c(111, 112, 145, 133, 113, 744, 754, 764, 734, 724));
```

I want to plot the variables side-by-side grouped by their `groupid`, hence I did the following:

```
mDat <- melt(dat, by = "groupid");
```

With this data set, I can easily plot the boxplots needed using ggplot2:

```
bp <- ggplot(mDat, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = groupid)) + 
geom_boxplot();
```

[image]

So far so good, however, I want to add an additional boxplot to the end of the plot, where all values in both variables are plotted to see the overall spread in a boxplot; I couldn't figure out how to modify the melted data set to get this result, e.g. add another group to `groupid` called `all`.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: what do you mean by "to the end of the plot"?

Comment: Just another variable called `all` with all the values in `var1` and `var2` but in two boxplots grouped by `groupid` as for `var1` and `var2`.

Comment: `ggplot(mDat, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = groupid)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = "all", fill = NULL))`

Comment: Thanks a lot Roland, that's perfect!